# NoSuchMethodError: skipInputBytes

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.1, javax.imageio

I am getting this strange Exception on JPEG upload. PNG works fine.

```
play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: skipInputBytes]]
    at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:289) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
    at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:383) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$handleAction$1$4$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:403) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$handleAction$1$4$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:403) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) [scala-library.jar:na]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$handleAction$1$4.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:403) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: skipInputBytes
    at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anon$1.apply(Action.scala:222) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(Action.scala:109) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(Action.scala:109) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
    at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:18) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:108) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:106) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: skipInputBytes
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.initReaderIDs(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_15]
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.<clinit>(JPEGImageReader.java:91) ~[na:1.7.0_15]
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReaderSpi.createReaderInstance(JPEGImageReaderSpi.java:85) ~[na:1.7.0_15]
    at javax.imageio.spi.ImageReaderSpi.createReaderInstance(ImageReaderSpi.java:320) ~[na:1.7.0_15]
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO$ImageReaderIterator.next(ImageIO.java:529) ~[na:1.7.0_15]
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO$ImageReaderIterator.next(ImageIO.java:513) ~[na:1.7.0_15]
```

I don't even know where it occurs exactly in my code. Any ideas?

Comment: Which version of imageio are you using?

Comment: java version "1.7.0_21"

Comment: The exception says you are using 1.7.0_15. Anyway, I meant the version of the jai library. I thinks you have an extra JAR file here, or does it come with the JDK?

Comment: I just have im4java 1.4.0 inside the project. But I do not think it comes from this library. I do not know why the error purports I have 1.7.0_15 installed. In fact it is 1.7.0_21.

Answer (score 1):

I was investigating this a bit. As you I also have 1.7.0_15 installed. `JPEGImageReader` comes with the JDK so I checked the sources. The method `skipInputBytes` wasn't there. Then I installed JDK 1.7.0_21 here the method is contained in `JPEGImageReader`.

So you just have to install the new JDK, or configure your IDE to use it if you have it installed already.

Comment: Thanks for you investigation. I have Java 1.7.0_21 installed and the program runs outside any IDE using the Play! Framework (which does not have a JDK configured as far as I know).

Comment: @user1625837 well it might uses the JDK which is on the path. Open a command line and type `java -version`. How are you running your application?

Comment: java -version
java version "1.7.0_21"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.3.9) (7u21-2.3.9-0ubuntu0.12.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)

Comment: To run the application, I type play-2.1.1/play then ~run

Comment: @user1625837 You are using the OpenJDK, maybe it doesn't include the newest version of `JPEGImageReader`.

Comment: If it does not include the newest version of `JPEGImageReader`, why does it then call `skipInputBytes`?

Comment: @user1625837 use an [Oracle JDK instead](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html) of the OpenJDK